# How to set ping timer in packet tracer 7.2.2 to wait for a reply

Tags: ping, packet-tracer

in windows we are able to set a timer in ms like this: 
`ping -w 500`

How can we do such thing for packet tracer 7.2.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For IOS, if you simply type the `ping` command with no address, you will be given options, including for timeout, and even have a choice of extended commands:

```
Router1#ping 
Protocol [ip]: 
Target IP address: 10.11.12.13
Repeat count [5]: 
Datagram size [100]: 
Timeout in seconds [2]: 
Extended commands [n]: y
Ingress ping [n]: 
Source address or interface: 
Type of service [0]: 
Set DF bit in IP header? [no]: 
Validate reply data? [no]: 
Data pattern [0x0000ABCD]: 
Loose, Strict, Record, Timestamp, Verbose[none]: 
Sweep range of sizes [n]: 
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.11.12.13, timeout is 2 seconds:
```

Comment: yes that works thank you. and at the time of pinging when I disconnect a link it shows this: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!U.!!!!! I want to know what is that dot (.) and what is that (U) sign? how differs ?

Comment: The dot means it timed out, and the U means it is unreachable.